# Avatar Pupettering with ThreeJS, ReadyPlayerMe, Kalidokit and MediaPipe

Tags: three.js, mediapipe, avatar, mo-cap

I try to animate a  [ReadyPlayer Me](https://readyplayer.me/fr) avatar using ThreeJS and [Kalidokit](https://github.com/yeemachine/kalidokit) (or something else) with [MediaPipe Hollisitc Pose](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/). Here is a working JSFiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/nxg5bp2h/1/

It almost works, but the code for Pose Estimation is all messed-up. I use the one inspired from [the scripts code](https://github.com/yeemachine/kalidokit/blob/c720d483df867996be96e2c3218e963da9190ecf/docs/script.js#L169) of Kalidokit but arms seems reversed and the legs going up ...

[image]

```
let  riggedPose = Kalidokit.Pose.solve(poselm3D, poselm,{runtime:'mediapipe',video: 
$('#mediapipe-video')[0]})
if (!riggedPose) { return; }

this.rigRotation('Hips', riggedPose.Hips.rotation, 0.7)
this.rigPosition('Hips', {
    x: -riggedPose.Hips.position.x, // Reverse direction
    y:  riggedPose.Hips.position.y + 1, // Add a bit of height
    z: -riggedPose.Hips.position.z // Reverse direction
}, 1, 0.07)

this.rigRotation('Chest', riggedPose.Spine, 0.25, 0.3)
this.rigRotation('Spine', riggedPose.Spine, 0.45, 0.3)

this.rigRotation('RightUpperArm', riggedPose.RightUpperArm, 1, 0.3)
this.rigRotation('RightLowerArm', riggedPose.RightLowerArm, 1, 0.3)
this.rigRotation('LeftUpperArm',  riggedPose.LeftUpperArm,  1, 0.3)
this.rigRotation('LeftLowerArm',  riggedPose.LeftLowerArm,  1, 0.3)

this.rigRotation('LeftUpperLeg',  riggedPose.LeftUpperLeg,  1, 0.3)
this.rigRotation('LeftLowerLeg',  riggedPose.LeftLowerLeg,  1, 0.3)
this.rigRotation('RightUpperLeg', riggedPose.RightUpperLeg, 1, 0.3)
this.rigRotation('RightLowerLeg', riggedPose.RightLowerLeg, 1, 0.3)
```

If someone can help me fix it, spot the error or to do the math ? I'm a little bit lost to understand where/why rotation are incorrect. May be all the RPM models are rigged another way ?!

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you swap the y and z rotations then you get a better result... it's still a bit unstable but it's at least in the right proximity.

```
let euler = new this.THREE.Euler(rotation.x * dampener, rotation.z * dampener, rotation.y * dampener)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Arms, I would found that swapping left to right worked significantly better, they seem to be mirrored. So instead of
`this.rigRotation('RightUpperArm', riggedPose.RightUpperArm, 1, 0.3)`
I did:
`this.rigRotation('LeftUpperArm', riggedPose.RightUpperArm, 1, 0.3)` and so on.

Also, you are trying to access the "Chest" bone on your rig with `this.rigRotation('Chest', riggedPose.Spine, 0.25, 0.3)`, however this bone does not exist on the ReadyPlayerMe rig. The RPM rig has "shoulderLeft" and "shoulderRight" bones in the Armature instead. When computing the quaternions, I assume that this is where it breaks, since the rotations are missing rotations in the traversal of the armature which lead to all bones lower in the tree being effected.